# EditText and Button Layout

Tags: android-layout

I want to have a EditText (as wide as it fits) and a button next to it. 
EditText(fill_parent - button width) + Button(wrap_content) = All (fill_parent)

How do I do this....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"/>
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This should work.